# serverside controls vs html controls from AJAX point of view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i know this question have been mentioned alot here but mine is a little more updated,
now with ASP.net 4 and new Ajax client templating plus JASON services.

so if i got all these new capabilities will i really need server side controls as long as i can bind on client side, create data-views on client side heck i can even use data-context and apply CRUD operations on clients side.

so i actually i wont need button_click server side event or what so ever...

i am asking this because i own some commercial Controls like Telerik and Component art and they both offer client side operations ow but still i am confused as to my knowledge creating these controls will still have to go through Page Life cycle

please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

The last Webforms app I created I had very few server controls on the page. Any save or update action I used plain HTML controls and jQuery for AJAX. I don't use any third-party control packs, but I know if you use jQuery you can find a jQuery plugin that will do what you need. There are hundreds of them out there and they're free.

If you are thinking about avoiding the page life cycle then I strongly suggest looking at the asp.net mvc framework. It allows for a lot more freedom and control over the HTML you produce. This makes it much easier to do AJAX and jQuery.